# How to disable freemarker caching in spring NON WEB

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

This is what I wrote on my spring context xml file:

```
    <bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/templates/" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="utf-8" />
    <property name="freemarkerSettings">
        <props>
            <prop key="template_update_delay">0</prop>
            <prop key="default_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But It doesn't work and subsequently my application is not able to refresh freemarker templates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<prop key="cache_storage">freemarker.cache.NullCacheStorage</prop>
```

BTW, `template_update_delay` of 0 should have effect, unless you get the template within the clock resolution after it was updated (that's 1/64s in most PC-s AFAIR). But of course if you don't want any caching, `NullCacheStorage` is the efficient solution.